# Switch Statement key event for 1

Tags: java, javafx, switch-statement

```
switch (event.getCode()) { 
       case UP:    Does Something; break; 
       case RIGHT: Does Something; break; 
       case DOWN:  Does Something; break; break; 
       case LEFT:  Does Something; break; break;
       case NUMPAD1:  Does Something; break;
```

This is probably a super simple answer but I just can't find it on the internet. The code works perfectly that's why I haven't shown it but I just want a Case Key for the number 1 not the NUMPAD 1 as shown in the code. 1 as in the key above Q.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These seem to be enum constants from JavaFX's [KeyCode](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/input/KeyCode.html).

According to these docs, the enum constant for key `1` is `DIGIT1`

Answer (score -1):

Just add:

```
case 1: Does Something;break;
```

Comment: What? This is obviously wrong and it still managed to get two upvotes? Let's hope they were just sock puppets ...

Comment: Yeah, this is why i asked the question because it wasn't Case 1. That just gives an error.